# Choose config.json version during database update after migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In my project I've defined two config.json files - config.Development.json, and config.Production.json. During executing **dnx ef database upgrade** only my Production config is selected (why is it, is it about alphabetical order?). Do you know how to change it? Is there a parameter to change my destination database during migrations with new Entity Framework?

Comment: A `--environment` option was added in [7f48d0c](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/commit/7f48d0c0fca054ed70bebe0e8d2c58ee3cc3df9b).

Comment: I have beta7 version of EF7 and still 
_dnx : System.Exception: TODO: Error: unrecognized option '--environment'_

Comment: Ok, pulled latest release (RC1 from dev) and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

These issues are still being kinked out and discussed. At the moment there is no way to specify your environment (or config file) when doing migrations and applying them.

Check out [The September Design Meeting Notes](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes-(September-17,-2015)#design-time-services) & issue [2294](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2294)